# Как получить номер сборки в react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Хочу выводить номер сборки в приложении, как можно ее получить в коде?! В смысле оно же генерируется автоматически и где-то должно храниться?! 
Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Установить модуль https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info

метод getBuildNumber()

```
let buildNumber = DeviceInfo.getBuildNumber();
// iOS: "89"
// Android: "4"
// Windows: ?
```